# How to extract text from a tag that is embedded under h2 using scrapy?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

[image]

I want to extract the name from a tag.

response.css('h2.product-names::text').get()

But it is returning:

```
<h2 class="product-names">

\<a target="\_blank" href="https://www.electronicsbazaar.com/dell-inspiron-13-7348-core-i5-5200u-2-20ghz-8gb-500gb-int-webcam-win-10-13-3-touch" title='Refurbished Dell Inspiron 13 7348 (Core I5 5Th Gen/8GB/500GB/Int/Win 10/13.3" Touch)'\>\\n                                                                                                            Refurbished Dell Inspiron 13 7348 (Core I5 5Th Gen/8GB/500GB/Int/Win 10/13.3" Touch)                                                                                                                                          </a>

</h2>
```

How can I get the text of the link ?

I tried:

```
response.css('h2.product-names').get()

<h2 class="product-names">

\<a target="\_blank" href="https://www.electronicsbazaar.com/dell-inspiron-13-7348-core-i5-5200u-2-20ghz-8gb-500gb-int-webcam-win-10-13-3-touch" title='Refurbished Dell Inspiron 13 7348 (Core I5 5Th Gen/8GB/500GB/Int/Win 10/13.3" Touch)'\>\\n                                                                                                            Refurbished Dell Inspiron 13 7348 (Core I5 5Th Gen/8GB/500GB/Int/Win 10/13.3" Touch)                                                                                                                                          </a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the name, if i read correctly from your screenshot, is contained in the  tag
The right xpath is:

```
response.xpath('//h2[@class="product-names"]/a/@title').extract()
```